# I can't figure out what is slowing my program down

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio-2010, stopwatch

I have created a Windows Form application that reads in a text file, rearranges the data, and writes to a new text file. I have noticed that it slows down exponentially as it runs. I have been using tracepoints, stopwatches, and datetime to figure out why each iteration is taking longer than the previous, but I can't figure it out. My best guess would be that it might have something to do with the way I'm initializing variables.

I'm not sure how helpful this snippet of code will be but maybe it will give some insight into my problem:

```
while (cuttedWords.Any())
        {
            var variable = cuttedWords.TakeWhile(x => x != separator).ToArray();

            cuttedWords = cuttedWords.Skip(variable.Length + 1);

            sortDataObject.SortDataMethod(variable, b);

            if (sortDataObject.virtualPara)
            {
                if (!virtualParaUsed)
                {
                    listOfNames = sortDataObject.findListOfNames(backgroundWords, ref IDforCounting, countParametersTable);
                }
                virtualParaUsed = true;

                printDataObject.WriteFileVirtual(fileName, ID, sortDataObject.listNames[0], sortDataObject.listNames[1],
                    sortDataObject.unit, listOfNames, sortDataObject.virtualNames);
                sortDataObject.virtualNames.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                int[] indexes = checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Cast<int>().ToArray();

                printDataObject.WriteFile(fileName, ID, sortDataObject.listNames[0], sortDataObject.listNames[1],
                    sortDataObject.unit, sortDataObject.hexValue[0], sortDataObject.stringShift, sortDataObject.sign,
                    sortDataObject.SFBinary[0], sortDataObject.wordValue, sortDataObject.conversions, sortDataObject.stringData, indexes, sortDataObject.conType);
            }

            decimal sum = ((decimal)IDforCounting) / countParametersTable * 100;
            int sum2 = (int)sum;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(sum2);
            ID++;
            IDforCounting++;
            b++;
        }
```

What is strange to me is that I know that each loop runs in a matter of milliseconds, but from the start of one loop to the start of the next, the time keeps increasing.

I apologize if this is not enough information to analyze my issue, but I'm not sure what else I can provide without showing my entire solution.

Thank you.

**EDIT: A better questions might be: what is a good way to analyze performance if stopwatches aren't doing the trick. I'd rather not have to download a profiler.**

Comment: how is the memory usage? If the memory usage increases quickly, that could be the reason.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've read about potential performance issues with `Skip` before. One solution was to use a `Batch` extension method instead (e.g. https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs?r=f85495b139a19bce7df2be98ad88754ba8932a28). However, that is pure speculation as I can't obviously debug your code against your data set.

Comment: @Matt That's a good question. I'll look into that. Can I track memory usage with breakpoints and/or tracepoints?

Comment: @user2340818 you can just use the process monitor from the system internal kit

Comment: what version of VS 2012? You can go straight to Analyse -> Performance WIzard in VIsual Studio

Comment: @sdrzymala VS 2010 Professional

Answer (score 0):

If its taking longer and longer, on each iteration, its probably related to the initial cuttedWords.any().

What type is cuttedWords? If its a database-backed enumerable, it will re-issue the sql statement on every iteration, which may or may not be what you want.

On the other hand, if this is a producer-consumer scenario, it may be that cuttedWords is locked by the producer, causing the consumer to be thread-locked while waiting for the producer to complete its action.

Also, the .reportProgress will cause the backgroundworker to raise an event on the thread that created it, potentially causing UI updates, so maybe try removing that line and see if it helps any. Then replace it with some code that only calls reportProgress if the progress has actually changed.

Comment: cuttedWords is type IEnumberable<string>

Comment: I don't think .reportProgess is the issue, since the entire loop runs quickly. It's between iterations that is the problem.

Comment: Could you try calling .ToList() on it, before the first iteration?

Comment: I will try that. What will that achieve?